# Snakemake use wildcards in path of python function

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

I have a simple function that read a file (one line) and get the first element after split.

```
def get_wc(wc):
    file = open(wc,"r")
    normalization_value = file.readline().split(' ')[0]
    return(normalization_value)
```

I use this function in a rule snakemake.

```
rule compute_fc:
input:
    "data/annotated_clones/{cdna}_paste_{lib}.annotated.bed"
output:
    "data/fold_change/{cdna}_paste_{lib}.fc.bed"
params:
    size_cdna=get_wc("data/wc_bed/cdna/{cdna}.wc.txt"),
    size_lib=get_wc("data/wc_bed/library/{lib}.wc.txt")
shell:'''
    awk -v cdna1={params.size_cdna} -v inp={params.size_lib} -v addon=1 -v FS='\t' -v OFS='\t' '/^chr/{{ratio=(($7+addon)/($8+addon))*(inp/cdna1);print $0,ratio}}' {input} > {output}
'''
```

I'm trying to get the value that get_wc function return and use it as params in snakemake rule.

But Snakemake don't get the path with the wildcards so it try to get the path with the wildcards and obviously it don't works.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/wc_bed/cdna/{cdna}.wc.txt'
```

Comment: What file did you expect this code to open? Because apparently a file named `data/wc_bed/cdna/{cdna}.wc.txt` does not exist, as the error message says…

Comment: Are you familiar with snakemake?
My function take a path then open a file and return a value. Pretty simple.
In snakemake you can use wildcards : for example {cdna}. this is like :
data/wc_bed/cdna/*.wc.txt
But you can give value to your cdna.
The probleme is that I don't know how snakemake use wildcard in path of input function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a lambda function, like this, should work:

```
params:
    size_cdna = lambda wildcards: get_wc(f"data/wc_bed/cdna/{wildcards.cdna}.wc.txt")
    size_lib = lambda wildcards: get_wc(f"data/wc_bed/library/{wildcards.lib}.wc.txt")
```

Take a look [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#non-file-parameters-for-rules) for the docs.