# Access specific element of a list returned by a function in Snakemake

Tags: python, function, snakemake

In my Snakemake workflow, I have defined a function that uses a file produced previously during the workflow, parses it and returns a list of 2 elements, for example :

```py
def get_param_value(wildcards) :
    # do stuff with the wildcards and some files
    return ["element1","element2"]
```

I would then like to use each value of the returned list as independent `params` in a subsequent rule, such as :

```
rule example :
    input :
        'input_file.txt'
    output :
        'output_file.txt'
    params :
        param1 = "element1", # First element of the list returned by get_param_value function
        param2 = "element2" # Second element of the list returned by get_param_value function
    shell :
        'somecommand -i {input} -smth1 {params.param1} -smth2 {params.param2} -o {output} ;'
```

I have tried using the function directly in the rule, with

```
params :
    param1 = get_param_value[0],
    param2 = get_param_value[1]
```

but I get a `TypeError : 'function' object is not subscriptable` (which is expected because it's a function).

Do you have a workaround for this ?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203852/snakemake-use-wildcards-in-path-of-python-function?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering and thanks to [Mario Abbruscato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10638652/mario-abbruscato)'s suggestions, this did the trick : I used lambda functions in the `params` directive of the rule to extract the elements of the list and assign them to different parameters :

```
rule example :
    input :
        'input_file.txt'
    output :
        'output_file.txt'
    params :
        params = lambda wildcards : get_param_value(wildcards)
    shell :
        'somecommand -i {input} -smth1 {params.param1[0]} -smth2 {params.param2[1]} -o {output} ;'
```

Comment: The first change is not necessary, it should be absolutely identical in Python? If it's not necessary, I'd remove it to focus the solution on the relevant part, which is to use: **lambda wildcard: function(wildcards)**

Comment: Yes, that was my thought too, but I didn't take the time to test it. In any case, thanks for the advice and I edited my answer accordingly !

Comment: Good! You're still calling the function twice which is unnecessary, if you just use indexing on the parameters like in my answer above. So one lambda would be enough, though no lambda is arguably even more readable ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to edit the double call to the lambda function ! It should be good now. I also agree that no lambda is way easier to understand ; I left it here because your following answer already contains a no-lambda solution (and maybe in some very specific cases the lambda might be preferable ?). But I can further edit this if needed !

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You can avoid lambdas and use a function just by placing its name without parentheses or brackets like `params: funcname`. The function with that name is then automatically called by Snakemake and the wildcards are passed along, too.

This can be applied in your context as follows:

```py
def get_param_value(wildcards) :
    return ["elem1","elem2"]

rule example :
    output :
        'output_file.txt'
    params : 
        string_list = get_param_value
    shell :
        'echo  -param1 {params.string_list[0]} -param2: {params.string_list[1]}'
```

You can run this yourself, it's a minimal (working) example that yields the following results when executed:

```sh
$ snakemake -np -c1

rule example:
    output: output_file.txt
    jobid: 0
    resources: tmpdir=/var/folders/5_/6_lmbd65717dly07dk7r7q200000gn/T

echo "param1: elem1" "param2: elem2"
```

Read more about using functions in rule attributes in the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#snakefiles-input-functions).

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
def get_param_value(wildcards,index) :
    with open('file_from_workflow_using_wildcards') as file :
        # do stuff
        res = ["element1","element2"] 
        return res[index]

rule example :
    input :
        'input_file.txt'
    output :
        'output_file.txt'
    params :
        param1 = get_param_value(wildcards,0), # First 
        param2 = get_param_value(wildcards,1) # Second 
    shell :
        'somecommand -i {input} -smth1 {params.param1} -smth2 {params.param2} -o {output} ;'
```

or better way using your function as it is in your code :

```
res = get_param_value(wildcards)

params :
    param1 = res[0],
    param2 = res[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both solutions failed. I tried the first one and got the `Error name 'wildcards' is not defined ` ; then I tried to use a lambda function in the params `param1 = lambda wildcards : get_param_value(wildcards.sample,0)` (sample is a wildcard present in rule input/output and get_param_value function and I got an InputFunctionException error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sample'`. Which is weird because the sample wildcard is properly understood by Snakemake in another lamba function used in the rule input.

Comment: About the 2nd solution : I assume the line `res = get_param_value(wildcards)` should be written between the function and the rule ? If so, when I tried it, I got the same NameError than before `name 'wildcards' is not defined`. When I use a lambda function `res = lambda wildcards : get_strandedness_qualimap(wildcards.sample)`, I get the same TypeError that incited to post the question : `'function' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: i can't imagine what  are "do stuff" and params you want to pass at function "get_param_value". It's up to you .  Please consider my solution as pseudo code , as I did considering your code.

Comment: Alright, I finally got it working. Your remarks were of great help and led me to the solution. Thanks !